# Is there a rule or pattern to figure out whether を or に should be used with 我慢する?

Tags: usage

The verb 我慢する means "to endure", "to put up with something or someone". According to my textbook, it is used with either に or を, but no further explanation is given.

I've been taking a look to several example sentences, and these are my impressions:

- 〇**を**我慢する is more frequent than 〇**に**我慢する
- When 〇 is a person, rather than an object, it is used 〇**に**我慢する (however, there are example sentences where に is used with objects, too).

Some of the example sentences I've found are:

> めんどくさいお兄ちゃん**に**我慢する。

> お金が貯まるまでそれ**を**我慢する。

> 食べることを我慢する。

Is there any rule or pattern to help me determine whether I should use に or を (or maybe even if there are cases where both are ok)?

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are semantically different.

- Xに我慢する means "to put up with X" (i.e., you **hate** X). Xに耐える is more common.
- Xを我慢する means "to put up with *the lack* of X", "to hold off on X", "to try to refrain from X" (i.e., you **want** X).

Comment: But we say stuff like 「痛みを我慢する」「隣がうるさいのを我慢する」 don't we.

Comment: @goldbrick そうですね…ちょっと良く分からなくなってきた…